# Access to printer from impersonated user on windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, aspose, topshelf

I'm developing windows service for downloading and printing documents(pdf, excel. word) under different credentials (need to add document in printing queue under different users). When I'm impersonate user I get an exception "Settings to printer are not valid". When I run service under my own context there is no exceptions and its works as expected

Here is windows service configuration:

```
var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
{
    x.Service<PrinterCentralPointService>(service =>
    {
        service.ConstructUsing(printerService => new PrinterCentralPointService());
        service.WhenStarted(printerService => printerService.Start());
        service.WhenStopped(printerService => printerService.Stop());
    });
    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
});
int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue;
```

Service:

```
public class PrinterCentralPointService {
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    public PrinterCentralPointService() {
        _timer = new Timer(1000) { AutoReset = false };
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    }
    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ps = new PrinterSettings(); // works fine
        using (var i = new ImpersonatedUser("login", "domain", "password"))
        {
            var ps = new PrinterSettings(); // default printer is not defined and etc...      // ... aspose code to send to printer
        }
    }
    public void Start() {
        _timer.Start();
    }
    public void Stop() {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

And ImpersonatedUser.cs

```
public class ImpersonatedUser: IDisposable 
{
    IntPtr userHandle;
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
    public ImpersonatedUser(string user, string domain, string password) 
    {
        userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool loggedOn = LogonUser(
            user,
            domain,
            password,
            LogonType.Batch,
            LogonProvider.Default,
            out userHandle);
        if (!loggedOn)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle);
    }
    public void Dispose() 
    {
        if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero) 
        {
            CloseHandle(userHandle);
            userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            impersonationContext.Undo();
            logger.Debug("Finished Impersonating user");
        }
    }
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool LogonUser(
        string lpszUsername,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        LogonType dwLogonType,
        LogonProvider dwLogonProvider,
        out IntPtr phToken
    );
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);
    enum LogonType: int 
    {
        Interactive = 2,
            Network = 3,
            Batch = 4,
            Service = 5,
            NetworkCleartext = 8,
            NewCredentials = 9,
    }
    enum LogonProvider: int 
    {
        Default = 0,
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you login to the PC under credentials that you use to impersonate? If not user folder and settings are not created.

Comment: @Wokuo yes, I did.

Comment: @Wokuo moreover, when I configure windows service to RunAs and provide credentials without impersonate, it works, but when I use impersonate (with same credentials, that service is running), it doesn't work

Comment: I would check another LogonType, I guess 'Service' would be more suitable in your case instead of 'Batch'.  Also I would try to use WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated method.

Comment: @Wokuo I tried all scenarios with Service type and LogonType, it doesn't work even in console app. Also I tried WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated, same results.